# How do i check if snapshot contains a specific value in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

When I run this code I get an error that says this:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(hasChild:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

My problem is how do I check if my snapshot contains **the value** user.email?

```
self.databaseRef.child("Test").child("xxx").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    if snapshot.hasChild((user!.email)!){
                        print("yess")
                    }else{
                        print("Not in db")
                    }


                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify your problem in your text. An email always contains a dot '.'. That is not allowed in the **key**. You check if the key contains the email, but that is not allowed. Structure your database like this:

```
"email": theemail
```

This way your **key** is *"email"* and your **value** is *theemail*. In the **value**, every string is allowed.

```
self.databaseRef.child("Test").child("xxx").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let values = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let email = values?["email"] as? String ?? "No email found"
    // OR
    if let email = values?["email"] as? String{
    //email (above declared variable) holds the value (the real email)
    }else{
    //no email
    }
    if email == (user!.email)!{

    }else{
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes, but my key is 0 and value is "test@test.com"

Comment: @EliasKnudsen yes, but in your method you search for a key which contains a dot, because you look up for a key which is the same as the users email. This is not allowed.

Comment: @EliasKnudsen See my edit, just compare the 2 variables.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works. It checks to see if the email field actually exists. I think you are getting the error because of the way you're checking for the actual user's email.

```
self.databaseRef.child("Test").child("xxx").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if snapshot.hasChild("email"){

        print("yess")

    }else{

        print("Not in db")
    }
})
```

`hasChild` returns true if the specified child path has (non-null) data.

Comment: Sorry it did not work, i will specify my question more

Comment: self.databaseRef.child("Test").child("xxx").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if snapshot.hasChild("email"){

        print("yess")

    }else{

        print("Not in db")
    }
}) This does only check if "email" is in the snapshot. I want to check if my snapshot contains user.email as a value